# Storybook 7 / angular - using argTypes in story

Tags: angular, storybook, angular16

I have a component...

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DisplayClassType, DisplayType, SizeType } from '../types/base.types';

@Component({
  selector: 'govc-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.scss'],
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() headerId = 'headerId-1';
  @Input() header = 'Title';
  @Input() displayClass: DisplayClassType = 'primary';
  @Input() displayType: DisplayType = 'flat';
  @Input() headerSize: SizeType = 'med';


  ngOnInit(): void {

    console.trace('**** Heaader Component');
  }
}
```

with story ..

```
import { Meta } from '@storybook/angular';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header.component';

export default {
  title: 'HeaderComponent',
  component: HeaderComponent,
  argTypes: {
    displayClass: {
      description: 'Button display class',
      defaultValue: 'primary',
      control: {
        type: 'select',
        options: ['primary', 'secondary'],
      },
    },
    displayType: {
      description: 'Button display type',
      defaultValue: 'outline',
      control: {
        type: 'select',
        options: ['outline', 'flat', 'basic'],
      },
    },
  },
} as Meta<HeaderComponent>;

export const Primary = {
  render: (args: HeaderComponent) => ({
    props: args,
  }),
  args: {
    headerId: 'headerId-1',
    header: 'Title',
    displayClass: 'primary',
    displayType: 'flat',
    headerSize: 'med',
  },
};
```

I'm trying to use argTypes to provide a select list of displayClass (types).

Currently the above story does not have any controls for displayClass or displayTypes.  Ideally it would be good to use the ts types directly .

Any thoughts?

If i run the above story there is just a - in place of the control.  I would like a select dropdown to allow developers to see the available types such as primary, secondary etc..

Comment: I think I faced similar issue, could you please provide full working example ?

Comment: https://github.com/bizappzone/min-repo-storybook/tree/main